# getJSON function, return encoded array from multiple mysql queries

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I'm wondering if it is possible to combine many queries into one array and return it.  The problem is that some of those queries already are arrays...here's what I mean:

JS:

```
function getNews() {
  $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getmainnews.php', function(data) {
    $('#fnews li').remove();
    daily = data.items;
      $.each(daily, function(index, mnews) {
        //append the data to listview
      });
    });
```

Here is the php file with the queries:

```
<?php
  include 'connect_to_mysql.php';
  mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
  $day = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM basket_news WHERE topic='daily' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
  $daily = array();
  while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($day)){
    $daily[] = $r;
  }

  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM basket_news WHERE topic='' ORDER BY id DESC"); 
    $mainnews = array();
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
      $mainnews[] = $r;
    }
?>
```

If I have more queries like this, how can I gather them together to be able to do something like:

```
echo json_encode(array("items" => $daily, "allitems" => $mainnews));
```

I understand that $daily has a LIMIT 1 with it, but others like $mainnews will be big arrays.  How would I set up the PHP echo and get it back in JS?  I guess if all else fails, I could do multiple ajax calls but that would be a waste...

Comment: Just join the arrays, json encode them, and return them to the ajax function.

Comment: Just how I did it there?

Comment: This all looks fine. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I'm an idiot...I actually wrote it right here and wrong in my original code.  I messed up in JS when I was getting it back.  Sorry for the waste of time!  Maybe this will help someone in the future :)